# wp_delete_post() force deleting post, override ignored

Tags: wordpress

I have set up a custom post type with a way to manage the posts on the front end of the site. On the front end users have the option to edit or delete posts.

When the user clicks delete, I run the wp_delete_post() function, to send the post to the trash. I don't want the post to bypass the trash, I would actually like the post to be sent to the trashcan.

The second parameter of the wp_delete_post is a boolean, true/false , which is supposed to dicate weather or not to bypass the trash.

The first is the ID of the post you'd like to delete.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post

Here is my function:

`wp_delete_post( $cpt_id, false );`

As you can see, I've set the second parameter to false, but it still bypasses the trash and gets deleted from the server.

Is this a bug that I should report to core, or am I missing something simple?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to ask this on [Wordpress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: woops, I thought that's where I was. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you never want to delete and always want to trash, you could use `wp_trash_post()` instead. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post)

However, that simply calls `wp_delete_post()` for you.

If none of your deletes are going to the trash, make sure that EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS is not set to 0 somewhere. (e.g. your wp-config.php) (http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Awesome thanks Cal, truly appreciated! wp_trash_post() works well for me. wp_delete_post() overrides and deletes the post from the db. Wasn't aware of wp_trash_post().